# How do I draw a solid line when texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to draw on my model a bump map of smooth lines to make a hair effect.
I notice that when I draw with a thin brush it starts looking more like Morse code than a line.

So how do I get the brush to draw a thin solid line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing it, but smoothness will be based upon number of vertices and size of UV map.

So subdividing your model may help, and possibly setting shading to smooth, but more likely than not **increasing the UV texture size** will be your best bet.

It generally defaults to 1024x1024, but when you draw a thin line, those pixels get stretched over the surface of your model, so resolution can make a big difference.

For broad strokes, small maps are OK... but for fine details, you need more pixels.  Try 2048x2048, or possibly more, especially if your model is large, or you need even more detail.

Comment: So it's all to do with scale then. I'll try a bigger image right now I'm using 2048 by 2048 but I'll double it. And I have to draw slowly or else my line becomes a a bunch of dots. I was wondering how to get faster emission of dots as I draw.

Comment: Oh, you might check your brush stroke spacing for that.  It defaults to 10% but something smaller, say 2% might do for something so finely detailed.

Comment: Just as a note, it is also beneficial to use Full Float when painting bump maps manually so that you get a good result.